# Highcharts Bar Chart Without Column

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

i'm new to highcharts.
I already browse in highcharts example. but, every time I look for the sample, it came with the column bar chart like this :

[image: bar chart]

All I want is like this :

[image: bar chart]

But I dont know how. Maybe you can help me figured it out.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set x/y pairs for each of points. Then set `column.grouping` to false: http://jsfiddle.net/27u9zuhj/

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            grouping: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [ [0, 5], [1, 3], [2, 4]]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [ [3, 2], [4, 2]]
    }]
```